# jQuery click event just trigger once

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm kinda new to jQuery, so this may be a silly question...
My problem is that i have a click event that triggers when I click any button with the class ajax-submit. What I'm trying to do is a simple multi-page form using ajax. It works great on the first step, but the second time I click on a button with the ajax-submit class, it won't work.

Here is the code I'm using for the AJAX form submitting:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".ajax-submit").click(function() {
var form_data = $('#unlockForm').serialize();
        $('.ajaxgif').removeClass('hide');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "formprocess.php",
data: form_data,
success: function(respuesta) {
    $('.ajaxgif').hide();
    $('#process-container').html(respuesta);
},
error: function() {
    $('.ajaxgif').hide();
    alert("Error! Please try again");
}
});
return false;
  });
});
```

And the form codes are simple like this

```
<form name="unlockForm" id="unlockForm" method="post">
      <input type="text" onFocus="if(this.value=='Introduce IMEI') this.value=''" value="Introduce IMEI" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Introduce IMEI';" name="imei" class="textbox part1" id="imei">
    <input type="button" class="ajax-submit inputbutton part1" value="Next" name="simple" id="next-imei">
    </form>
```

In both forms the buttons have the ajax-submit class, I checked and I don't have any typo mistake, you may ask why I don't use submit buttons, well, I tried but I didn't figured out how to manage the submit event correctly, it kept recharging the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `click` event  is not attached to the new `.ajax-submit` elements.
You will need to use delegate event like with `on` or `delegate` to do so.

```
$("#process-container").on('click','.ajax-submit',function() {
    var form_data = $('#unlockForm').serialize();
    $('.ajaxgif').show(); 
    // I think you didn't really meant: $('.ajaxgif').removeClass('hide');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "formprocess.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(respuesta) {
            $('.ajaxgif').hide();
            $('#process-container').html(respuesta);
        },
        error: function() {
            $('.ajaxgif').hide();
            alert("Error! Please try again");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Table of delegate event functions:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

`on` Useful [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as
>   direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event
>   occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the
>   element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.
>
> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.
>
> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much! Actually with the ajaxgif part, that piece of code wasn't mine, I took it from another example, I don't even have yet an "ajaxgif" element yet, I think that removeClass('hide') would do the trick, but isn't the best way to do it, as there're methods like show. I'm thinking of doing it with some fadeIn effect, but that's offtopic :P