# jQuery click event does not trigger after one time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm new to this site and jQuery. I don't know if this is common knowledge or not but I have a problem with the submit button like this thread:
[jQuery click event just trigger once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630593/jquery-click-event-just-trigger-once)
But my code is this:
I have a table like this on my page:

```
<table border="1">
     <tr><th>Song</th><th>Listen</th></tr>
     <tr><td>Singer - Song </td>
     <td><form class="frm" id="lis_0" name="name">
              <input type="hidden" class="url" value="somelink" id="url_0" />
       <input class="submit" type="submit" onmouseover="activate(this, 0)" onmouseout="deactivate(this, 0)" value="Listen" />
     </form>
     </td>
  </tr>
      <tr><td>Singer - Song </td>
     <td><form class="frm" id="lis_1" name="name">
              <input type="hidden" class="url" value="somelink" id="url_1" />
       <input class="submit" type="submit" onmouseover="activate(this, 1)" onmouseout="deactivate(this, 1)" value="Listen" />
     </form>
     </td>
  </tr>
      ....
      ....
</table>
```

And I'm getting information from these table to the `player.php` like below:

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type    : "GET",
                    url     : "player.php",
                    data    : {"url" : $("#active").val() },
                    success : function(response){
                        alert(response);
                        $("#response div").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $("#response div").remove();
                            $("#response").append($(response).hide().fadeIn());
                        });
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

And this `player.php` returns a div, something like this:

```
'<div class="mp3player">
                <p id="audioplayer_1">Alternative content</p>  
                <script type="text/javascript">  
                    AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer_1", {
                    soundFile: "'.$file.'",  
                    titles: "'.$title.'",  
                    artists: "'.$artist.'",  
                    autostart: "yes"
                    });  
                </script>
            </div>'
```

And I'm appending this to response div on my page, after deleting the ones before. It works well but I have another submit event for searching these songs:

```
$('form[id^="search"]').submit(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type    : "GET",
                    url     : "search.php",
                    data    : {"searchText" : $("#searchText").val() },
                    success : function(response){
                        $('div[id="results"]').fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $('div[id="results"]').remove();
                            $("#leftcolumn").append($(response).hide().fadeIn());
                        });
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

When I run a search on my page from this form:

```
<form class="search" id="searchForm" name="name">
<input type="text" value="" id="searchText" name="searchString" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

That `search.php` works and replaces my table with new results. And then my table's forms does not work for a second time.
Sorry for the long post but I don't what to post and what to not. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Instead of `.click(function(){ ... })` use `.on('click', function(){...})`. Just like the accepted answer to the question you link to.

Comment: @Matt `.click()` and `.on('click',function()` eventually are the same thing

Comment: @wirey No. `.on()` is equivalent to `.bind()` (which is deprecated), which applies the event handler to all current *and future* elements that match the selector. `.click` just binds the handler to currently existing elements.

Comment: @Matt  No, that's only if you delegate.. meaning `$(parent).on('click','element',function()`.. whereas `$(element).on('click',function()` is equivalent to bind().. and shorthand .click()

Comment: @dystroy and look at his first comment.. the way he's using .on is not delegating.. which is equivalent to bind().. and .click()

Comment: @Wirey Yes, you're right, I hadn't read his comment in details, I just saw 'on' which I had put in my answer.

Comment: `.on('click', function(){...})` doesnt work and it doest run for even the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result:

```
$('form[id^="lis"]').live('click' , '.submit', function(){
```

`.live()` binding solved my problem. And if you want to use `.on()` binding, ajax loaded content should not be same as content already binded with that function. At least as far as i understood from this
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-bind-events-to-ajax-loaded.html
Thanks everyone

Comment: live is deprecated, you should use on now. Please look at http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 3):

If you're replacing the `.submit` elements, the event handler you first defined with `$('.submit').click(function(){` aren't linked to any present elements.

In order to have event handlers linked to any '.submit' element including the ones created lated (this your search.php),  you need to use the [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function :

```
$('document').on('click', '.submit', function(){...})
```

This will apply to all '.submit' elements of the documents, even those not existing at the time of the call.

You may have a more precise selector than 'document' if you can define one.

Comment: yes im replacing my whole table which .submit is class of my input buttons. But `$('document').on('click' , '.submit', function(){`
doesn't work either.  And it doesn't work even for the first time

Comment: " it doesn't work even for the first time" ? Are you sure ? No typo ? If `$('.submit').click(function(){` worked there is no reason `on` wouldn't work...

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
   google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
   google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    $('.submit').click(function(){
     
     return false;
    });
     
    $('form[id^="search"]').submit(function(){
     
     return false;
    });
   });
  </script>

Comment: Thats both functions without their code. i just want to catch button click and return false, to see if code works but only this one catches. `$('document').on('click' , '.submit', function(){` does not work

Comment: maybe because of my version of jquery??  how can i load latest?? i tried but could not accomplish one thats working. can u write me your own script src tags

Comment: I'd suggest `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yea i got it and `$(document).on('click' , '.submit', function(){` works but only once.

Comment: i solved my version problem and this was the reason of why `on` event did not work. Any other ideas?