# Why would blur event only fire one time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

So I have a similar function with a click event and it works every time, but this function only fires once? Any idea?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.changecat').blur(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var catId = event.currentTarget.id;
    var catValue = $(event.currentTarget).val();
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: window.location.pathname,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        changeCat: catId,
        catValue: catValue
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $('#categorized').html(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Part of the HTML:

```
<div id="categorized" style="margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px;" class="col-sm-12">
  @foreach ($category as $c)
    @if ($c->category !== "")
    <div id="{{$c->id}}" class="col-sm-4"><button type="button" data="{{$c->id}}" class="{{$c->id}} category btn btn-danger center-block">{{$c->category}}</button><br/><input id="{{$c->id}}" class="changecat center-block text-center" type="text" value="{{$c->category}}" /></div>
    @endif
  @endforeach   
</div>
```

Comment: Because you replace the DOM  including event handlers of the div. How did you even manage to ask this question without finding the duplicate? OR this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630593/jquery-click-event-just-trigger-once

Comment: Thanks, it didn't come up. I guess i focused on blur event trigger